# Initialize a Room Impulse Response using reverberation time(T60)

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, audio-processing

I am doing Speech dereverberation using Non-negative matrix factorization.

To be precise, I am working on this paper by Nasser(paris.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/nasser-icassp2015.pdf) which involves obtaining optimal solution for a Room Impulse Response(Equation 10). So, for that I need to initialize H first. He has mentioned in the paper that "Each row of H was initialized identically using a linearly decaying envelope"(Section 4, at the end of page 3). I need to initialize an impulse response(H) such that its reverberation time(T60) is 300 ms. Let the length of H be 10.

This is what I tried but its an arbitrary solution.

```
x=1:10;
h = exp(-x/2);
H = repmat(h,600,1);
```

This will give me a H of dimension 600 * 10.
But, I don't understand how to use T60 for the initialization in MATLAB.

Comment: There is http://dsp.stackexchange.com specifically for the questions like this one. It is also worth to mention the Matlab package you are working with.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks. I have posted the question there.
I am not using any toolbox, to be precise.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24481/initialize-a-room-impulse-response-using-reverberation-timet60

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. If you're trying to create a reverberation effect, then H should just be a vector, it seems to me that you have a matrix with 10 columns. When creating a reverb effect, you generally get your impulse response and convolve it with you audio signal. In this case, h seems pretty arbitrary and I don't know if it will give you the amount of reverb you are looking for. However, if you wanted to implement h as an impulse response for a reverb, all you have to do is convolve your audio signal with ythe impulse response.

```
[x, fs] = audioread('myaudio.wav');
y = conv(x,h);
```

If you had an impulse response from a recording and an impulse response from the room the recording was made, you could apply deconvolution to remove the reverb using the deconv function in Matlab.

You should be able to work out a formula so that h is just a exponentially decaying vector that takes roughly 300ms  to die (although actually hearing that may be tricky)

If you want to get really advanced with your impulse response calculations, I recommend trying an image source approach to creating your impulse response. Check out the following paper(old, but golden);

http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/cmsc828d_audio/AllenBerkley79.pdf

If you're interested in blind deconvolution, this might be of interest to you.

https://www.academia.edu/1370250/Predictive_deconvolution_and_kurtosis_maximization_for_speech_dereverberation

A slight caveat, deconvolution and room reverberation is a very tricky business. The image source model given above, while interesting and effective, doesn't really capture the complexity of reverberation and dereverberation. There are several things that can affect the sound (standing waves, etc) I can't guarantee you that simply calculating the RT60 using just a decaying exponential vector and deconvolution will yield amazing results. Still though, wort a shot and lots of fun!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not trying to create a reverb effect.
Actually, I am working on this paper by Nasser(http://paris.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/nasser-icassp2015.pdf) which involves obtaining optimal solution for a Room Impulse Response(Equation 10). So, for that I need to initialize H first. He has mentioned in the paper that "Each row of H was initialized identically using a linearly decaying envelope"(Section 4, at the end of page 3). I want to know what he meant by that. 
And as you said about the formula, that is what I want to know.

Comment: He means that H is a matrix filled with identically decaying exponential vectors I believe. If you type the following into matlab; H(1,:) == H(2,:) you will get a vector of 1's. this means that the values in row 1 and row 2 are identical. If you do this test on any row in the matrix you will get the same result.

Comment: Yes, I get that all the rows are identical. But I don't understand how to initialize a particular row such that its reverberation time is 300 ms. What is the relation here between initialization and T60?

Comment: Each STFT frame is 32 ms (as in paper), you have 10 frames, so approximately 300ms. If you quote the paper in original question, it would be way easier to answer you.

Comment: Done. 
Yes, let it be 300 ms. How to find an envelope that decays 60db in 300 ms? That's what I want to know because then I can use repmat after getting it for one row.